# Passing arguments to a secured dropwizard resource

Tags: java, rest, jackson, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

I have a resource, which is secured, if I remove the authentication, it appears to work, but then without the security, then what is the point?

Here is my code :

```
@POST
@Path("/secured")
@Timed
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@UnitOfWork
@RolesAllowed("mainUser")
public Response aliveSecure(@Auth User user, CustomRequest test)
{
    CustomResponse resp = new CustomResponse();

    System.out.println(test.getMessage());
    return Response.status(Response.Status.ACCEPTED).entity(resp).build();
}
```

The CustomRequest and CustomResponse types are pretty standard POJOs, they just hold a string called "Message" - they are actually identical, but this is just an exercise I am trying to complete for the sake of learning DropWizard.

Now, if I remove the @Auth stuff here, and the @RolesAllowed, etc - making it a insecure, then the method performs as normal - but as is, this is the error I get when trying to start the application.

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
! [[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public CustomRequest at index 0.;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [auth manual](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.0/docs/manual/auth.html) reads it clear -

> If you want to use `@Auth` to inject a custom principal type into your
>   resource.

Hence you shall ensure adding the following to your `Service` that extends `io.dropwizard.Application`

```
@Override
public void run(SomeConfigThatExtendsConfiguration config, Environment environment) throws Exception {
    ....
    environment.jersey().register(new AuthValueFactoryProvider.Binder<>(User.class));
}
```

Comment: @MickeyThreeSheds Good to know. :)